# How to randomly select samples in R if same values exist in a dataset?

Tags: r, select, sample

I have a dataset with several columns and each column has thousands of data. And I would like to randomly select some samples. However, there are some same values exist in each column. How could I make R to select samples without replacement, but make sure these same values could be selected randomly?

For example, a dataset called df:

```
df <- c(1,2,3,3,3,4,5,6,6)
```

How can I use `sample(x=df, size=5, replace=False)` to get a result like this:

`newdf: #> [1] 3 3 2 5 6`.   I just want R can select same values randomly whatever how many times they occur in the result. But not use `replace=TRUE`, because I don't want duplicated values like this:
`newdf: #> [1] 1 1 2 2 3`.

I'm a newbie for R, I'll appreciate if you could give me any advice!

Comment: What is wrong with `sample(df, 5)` ?

Comment: I'm wondering how to modify this function to get the result I want? If I use replace=False, will 3 can only be selected once but not twice or three times since it doesn't allow duplicated values appear? @RonakShah

Comment: I don't think so. When I do `sample(df, 5)` I see 3 appearing thrice. `replace = FALSE` is by default in `sample`.

Answer (score 0):

@RonakShah's comment is correct - just use `sample(df, 5, replace = FALSE)`.

Explanation:
Imagine each value in `df` is indexed, 1, 2, 3, ..., n.

Sampling without replacement just means that one value, at a specific index, is drawn at a time from `df`.  If the value at index 1 is drawn, then index 1 in `df` is no longer a valid draw for subsequent draws in the sequence.

So the `replace` argument doesn't pay attention to duplicated *values*, but rather it ensures there are no duplicated *indices* of `df` selected.

From the [docs](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/sample.html):

> the probability of choosing the next item is proportional to the weights amongst the remaining items.